# Change coordinates precision while serializing geodjano objects

Tags: geojson, geodjango, django-serializer

I have a GeoDjango polygon model as below

```
class PolygonFeature(models.Model):
    shapefile = models.ForeignKey(Shapefile,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='polygon_shp')
    geom = models.PolygonField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.shapefile.filename) + "-" + str(self.pk)
```

I am adding polygon to model via LayerMapping in which out is the shapefile

```
mapping = {
'shapefile':{'id':'survey_pk'},
'geom': geom,
}
lm = LayerMapping(model, out, mapping, transform=transform, encoding='iso-8859-1')
lm.save(verbose=False)
```

I need to change coordinates precision while serializing polygon object geometry to GeoJSOn

```
feat = PolygonFeature.objects.filter(shapefile=obj)
json_obj = serialize('geojson', feat)
```

Current

```
 {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": {
  "type": "name",
  "name": "EPSG:4326"
},
"features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "shapefile": 53,
      "pk": "45269"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            75.6083423241,
            31.315054275
          ],
          [
            75.5543398801,
            31.30543373742
          ],
          [
            75.5970812345,
            31.2980635331
          ],
          [
            75.6543504465,
            31.30345354185
          ],
          [
            75.6035348241,
            31.315035375
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "change coordinates precision"? Please add an example of required precision

Comment: I'm sorry, but "I need to <insert incomprehensible requirement here>" is not a proper question. Can you clarify what you want to do? What is the result you want to obtain?

Comment: Round off coordinate values to 5 decimal place